# Base Fee vs Gas Price EIP1559

Tags: eip-1559

With the new eip1559 on August 5, I was wondering whether we have to use BaseFee or GasPrice, many dexes like uniswap still specify a gasPrice (ex: 20 gwei) but what confuses me is that with the new ethereum upgradal the gasPrice is the same for everyone and is called the baseFee. I don't understand why then we still have to specify the gasPrice when it should be predetermined by the ethereum network. I also don't see any mention of miner tip where we can specify it